# Are C sockets and socket.io/Websockets from React compatible?

Tags: c, reactjs, sockets, websocket, socket.io

So I've created a simple chatserver / chatclient in C. The chatclient reads from stdin and outputs to stdout. The goal is to adapt this to a frontend web UI. I was thinking of using React and it seems like the most commonly used socket libraries are socket.io or Websockets.

So my big question is: can I replace my chatclient I've built in C with a React chatclient that uses socket.io or Websockets to connect to my chatserver in C?

Are the two sockets compatible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is both "Yes" and "No", but the [answer given by justcivah](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65312063/4025095) probably should have been "No", since it lacks vital information (**edit**: the referenced answer was deleted)...

The reason is that WebSockets is a protocol, so your server needs to understand that specific protocol.

The WebSockets protocol usually runs as an additional layer over TCP/IP sockets (which is the only layer you probably have on your C chatserver), and it includes additional ("header") data before the "message" (payload). WebSockets also require an HTTP based handshake (though other possible handshakes might be added in the future).

There are a number of different WebSocket libraries in C that could help you implement the WebSockets protocol in your C chatserver - just search for C WebSocket Framework or something like that.